# Автономное PHP-приложение, живущее на TCP-порту

Tags: php, сокет, архитектура, tcp, протоколы

Помогите разобраться с вопросом. Весь день уже с ним мучаюсь. Я в PHP не профессионал, но и не новичок. Можно ли реализовать следующую идею?
Берем TCP-сервер на PHP, благо существует куча готовых вариантов. Создаем на его фундаменте PHP-приложение. То есть, фактически, запросы к приложению будут происходить через TCP-сокет. Приложение приняло запрос, обработала его, например дернула из БД аккаунт пользователя, и вернуло обратно клиенту. Получается, что само приложение не умирает, а существует в любой момент времени, имея свое собственное состояние. Можно глобально хранить различные свойства, конфигурации, списки онлайн пользователей. Всё это будет крутится в одном пространстве имен. Доступ к приложению, как я писал выше, осуществляется по TCP-сокету на указанный порт. В итоге, мы получаем полностью автономное PHP-приложение, которое бесконечно будет находится в памяти и обрабатывать запросы. Оно будет иметь свое постоянное состояние, которое сохраняется от запросу к запросу.
Это вообще возможно реализовать? Теоретически, есть готовые TCP-сервера, написанные на PHP и способные обрабатывать десятки тысяч запросов в секунду. Где тут подводные камни? Стоит ли вообще развиваться в таком направлении или просто забить и использовать классические подходы?

Comment: Минус потому что https://tproger.ru/explain/xyproblem/ а вообще это называется вебсокет

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Я прекрасно знаю о вебсокетах. Я говорю о попытках развернуть php-приложение на TCP-порту. Вебсокеты мне не нужны. Грубо говоря, приложение будет висеть в памяти вечно, ожидая коннекты по tcp ЛОКАЛЬНО, а не по сети.

Comment: а **какая разница**, я стесняюсь спросить?

Comment: Вебсокеты это просто возможность отправлять сообщения в рилтайме. А я говорю о фундаментальной архитектуре проекта. TCP-сокеты и Вебсокеты это совершенно разные вещи. WS это отдельный протокол, работающий поверх HTTP, который, в свою очередь, работает над TCP

Comment: Вам шашечки или ехать? Нужен демон который висит и отвечает. Чем вебсокет конкретно не устраивает? И это даже если не спрашивать, чем не устраивает классический HTTP демон

Comment: Тут вопрос архитектуры, а не технологии. Можно и на Вебсокетах извратиться. Правда, я не понимаю, зачем. Мне нужно локально, из скрипта, обратиться к веб-приложению. В чем тут выигрыш WS, я не понимаю. Я вообще могу UDP использовать, не суть важна. Вопрос тут в подходе и в трезвости идеи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, Вы всё написали правильно.

И я вообще люблю велосипеды, так что совершенно не встаю в позицию "что за чушь, немедленно прекратить!"

Но есть несколько подводных камней.

Давайте попробуем разобрать их по очереди.

1. Смысл приложения, которое хранит своё состояние, я так понимаю, в том, что есть экономия - не надо это состояние где то хранить и восстанавливать.

Так и в обычном web - приложении есть возможность хранить такой объект - это паттерн singleton.

2. Почему выстрелила stateless-идеология? Потому что она крайне проста. Когда вы работаете со страницей, которая должна сделать что очень простое - типа, показать состояние корзины, и дать возможность его модифицировать - то это легко объяснить как программисту, так и тестеру. Приложения дробятся на маленькие аккуратненькие кусочки, которые - теоретически - можно переиспользовать.

Если Вы заводите приложение с глобальным состоянием - это то, что называется "монолит". Это само по себе - не плохо и не хорошо. Но современные подходы - это слабосвязанные системы, котрые можно "расчленить на части" и каждую из частей протестировать или переписать по отдельности. Это называется "микросервисная архитектура"

3. "есть готовые TCP-сервера, написанные на PHP и способные обрабатывать десятки тысяч запросов в секунду" - совершенно верно. В тот момент, когда раздают статику. В тот момент, когда сервер начинает делать что то реально затратное - его способность отвечать на запросы снижается. И если у Вас монолит - то у вас возникает бутылочное горлышко. А стейтлесс - системы хорошо поддаются горизонтальному масштабированию - просто надо поставить больше серверов.
4. В комментариях не зря пишут про вебсокет. Это хорошая современная технология для поддержания постоянного коннекта. "Стоит ли вообще развиваться в таком направлении или просто забить и использовать классические подходы?" - думаю, что самое лучшее - это использовать примущества обеих миров. И каждый раз выбирать архитектуру, соответствующую задаче: когда то использовать больше стетлесса, когда то - наоброт, добавить больше монолитностии  получить преимущества сильносвязанной системы.
5. Пути развития технологий могут быть весьма странными. Я думаю, многие программисты реально в шоке от того, как сложен современный браузер и какой невообразимый стек технологий скрывается за обычным "заказом пиццы", например.

И, конечно, многие из нас думали, как было бы клёво, если бы просто была возможность передавать "окошки", генерируемые на сервере, на клиента. Никакого браузера, никаких глупых css, html, верстки, бутстрепа, встраивания тридцати систем слежения за пользователем, айфреймов, ошибок в Js - чистенькая архитектура, просто вместо того, что приложение выполняетмся локально - оно может быть "растянуто" между клиентом и сервером.

Наверняка, такие решения есть, и они могут быть даже не очень сложными. У меня чешутся руки сделать что то подобное на wasm'е.

Но - под завязку - у меня есть еще более впечатляющая по простоте идея: а зачем нам приложение - браузер и вообще приложение? Давайте с сервера гнать RTSP - поток. Его - видеопоток - будет показывать браузер или модифицированный плеер. А обратно - отсылать нажатия клавиш и клики мышкой. А всё остальное - срендерим на сервере и преобразуем в видео.

Comment: Вот поэтому меня и поразила эта идея своей, казалось быть, простотой. Иметь на бэкенде цельное и самостоятельное приложение, работающее в изолированной среде. Оно не разброшено по различным комнатам, называемые Redis и Memcached. Мы имеем единое пространство имен, в котором сколько угодно долго хранятся все настройки, конфигурации, параметры, сессии и всё прочее. Нам не нужно каждый раз дёргать, скажем, файлы настроек приложения из файлов, всё разом грузим при инициализации и пользуемся сколько угодно.
Если не это. Остаются сторонние кэш-сервисы. Ридис и прочие. Совсем другая архитектура

Comment: Та идея, котрая Вам понравилась, видимо, называется "монолитная трехзвенная архитектура". Вы можете сделать какой то проект, который будет основан на этой архитектура, и сами поймёте её преимущества и недостатки. Кстати, вот первый: у tcp - коннекта надо следить за состоянием: не разорвалось ли? а как восстанавливать? и т.п.

Comment: Тут, скорее знаете. Попытка работы над эвристическим проектом. Поиграться, так сказать. А вдруг зайдет?
А про tcp-коннект. Само приложение будет жить на готовом tcp-сервере. К примеру, Workerman. Вещь очень классная. Допустим, со своей задачей он будет справляться на ура. Остается вопрос в клиенте. Корректно соединяться с tcp-сервером (самим приложением), качественно обрабатывать возникшие ошибки и прочее. Это уже вопрос времени. Сама идея. Уход от классических форм разработки PHP-приложений.

Comment: Ага а потом у него потечёт память.

Comment: @Ипатьев - на этот вопрос индустрия уже знает ответ, просто время от времени надо будет контейнер с приложением "пристреливать" и перезапускать... Этому мы научились еще во времена рельсов.

Answer (score 3):

> Получается, что само приложение не умирает, а существует в любой момент времени, имея свое собственное состояние

К сожалению, на практике только кажется, что это состояние будет приносить плюсы. С точки зрения организации программы это кажется удобством, но на самом деле это проблема. Самое главное, что вы не сможете ничего существенного там хранить (разве что конфигурацию). Ведь если вы храните состояние в памяти, то сбой приложения (или железа) приведет к потере пользовательских данных.

Вторая проблема, это масштабирование. Если один экземпляр приложения с нагрузкой перестанет справляться, то запустить на втором сервере еще один так просто не получится. Так как состояние одного экземпляра приложения и второго нужно будет как-то синхронизировать. Либо иным способом (типа sticky sessions) добиваться того, чтобы нам при обработке запроса не нужно было знать состояние другого экземпляра приложения.

Я с php не знаком вообще, но сервера на java и python так и работают, с поправкой на то, что они stateless так, как хранить состояние -  это антипаттерн и плохая практика.